# Expo Go there was problem loading the requset app

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

i have run a react native with Expo application .
i used yarn package manger run the commands

```
yarn install 

then expo start
```

there is  an warning upper
WARNING: expo-cli has not yet been tested against Node.js v17.8.0.
If you encounter any issues, please report them to https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues

expo-cli supports following Node.js versions:

- > =12.13.0 <13.0.0 (Maintenance LTS)
- > =14.0.0 <15.0.0 (Active LTS)
- > =15.0.0 <17.0.0 (Current Release)

and expo go show this message there was problem loading the requset app

node.js version v16.14.2

Expo version 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

u are using current release version which is not yet tested with expo
use LTS version

first check you node version
go to cli then enter node -v
if it is not the required version then install the required version using the command
npm install -g node@version

the recommended version is 16.14.2 (LTS)

Comment: i'm  using  node version v16.14.2

Comment: then downgrade expo version to last stable update